# active link css not showing shadow

Tags: javascript, css

On this webpage: http://www.riversidelab.com/dental-lab-services/all-ceramic/bruxzir-solid-zirconia-crowns-bridges.aspx

Please click on blue button VIDEO, it slides over the video. Great. The button goes to active mode: black text color. But it is not showing up the bottom shadow css. How do I make the active button show bottom shadow?

```
.btnBlue {
  background-color: #34aadc;
  border-color: #34aadc;

  color: white;
    font-style: oblique;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: Frutiger47LightCnBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -10px #000000;
}
.btnBlue:hover,
.btnBlue:focus,
.btnBlue:active,
.btnBlue.active {
  background-color: #249ed2;
  border-color: #218ebd;

  color: #333333;
}
.btnBlue.disabled:hover,
.btnBlue.disabled:focus,
.btnBlue.disabled:active,
.btnBlue.disabled.active,
.btnBlue[disabled]:hover,
.btnBlue[disabled]:focus,
.btnBlue[disabled]:active,
.btnBlue[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btnBlue:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btnBlue:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btnBlue:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btnBlue.active {
  background-color: #34aadc;
  border-color: #34aadc;

  color: #333333;
}




$(function() {

    var activeNavButton = null;

    $('.nav_button').on('click', function(evt) {

        if (activeNavButton) {
            activeNavButton.removeClass('active');
        }

        activeNavButton = $(this);

        activeNavButton.addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: It is the reverse of what is currently happening.

Comment: Now the current active link is without any shadow while the others are with the bottom shadow.

Try changing the condition and that should pretty much help it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    var activeNavButton = null;

    $('.nav_button').on('click', function(evt) {

        if (activeNavButton) { // activeNavButton will always be null
            activeNavButton.removeClass('active');
        }

        activeNavButton = $(this);

        activeNavButton.addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Instead you can have this way:

```
$(function() {

    var activeNavButton = null;

    $('.nav_button').on('click', function(evt) {
        activeNavButton = $(this);
        $('.nav_button').each (function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        activeNavButton.addClass('active');
    });

});
```

I guess the problem is with your css

```
.btn:active, .btn.active {
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

The opacity value that you have given was very relatively low (.125) that you couldn't see the change.

I guess this makes some difference.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Your code is up LIVE now. Shadow still not showing up. http://www.riversidelab.com/dental-lab-services/all-ceramic/bruxzir-solid-zirconia-crowns-bridges.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A very small mistake you are doing. Before you assign a value to a variable, you are trying to access/use it, which is technically wrong. You better first assign the value to your variable `activeNavButton` and the try to use it.

here is what I mean:

```
$('.nav_button').on('click', function (evt) {
    activeNavButton = $(this);
    if (activeNavButton) {
        activeNavButton.removeClass('active');
    }
    activeNavButton.addClass('active');
});
```

But, here I dont understand why you are checking if your that variable exists or not. So why to remove the same class and then add that again. In jQuery when you do `.addClass()` that checks if that class already exists or not in that element. If exists doesn't nothing and if not, adds that class. So, you don't need to worry about that for duplicate class in the same element to be added.

So the code should be:

```
$('.nav_button').on('click', function (evt) {
    activeNavButton = $(this);
    activeNavButton.addClass('active');
});
```

Now, again if you just want to add the class in the button, there is no need to take a variable for this. So, this should be:

```
$('.nav_button').on('click', function (evt) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

but, here in your case what I understand is you want to remove active class from other buttons and want add that class in just clicked button. So, this code should be:

```
$('.nav_button').on('click', function (evt) {
    $('.nav_button').removeClass("active"); // will remove active class from all the .nav_button
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Hope, this helps!